# your help on event handling

Tags: vba, excel

I am learning event handling of vba. here is my first try out.

```
'in sheet Object
Dim WithEvents engine As MCengine

Private Sub engine_OnEachTrial(ByVal i As Integer)
progressBar = Application.Floor(i * 30 / engine.numOfPaths, 0.001)

With ActiveSheet.Range("E10").Characters(start:=0, Length:=progressBar).Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .FontStyle = "Bold"
    .Size = 11
    .ColorIndex = 16
End With
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim btn As Button
Dim rng As Range
Set engine = New MCengine
With ActiveSheet
Set rng = .Range("E9")
Set btn = .Buttons.Add(rng.Left, rng.Top, rng.Width, rng.Height)
    With btn
    .Caption = "Run MC simulation"
    .OnAction = "runMC"
    End With
End With

End Sub

Sub runMC()

engine.process = 1
engine.numOfPaths = 30
engine.start

End Sub
```

The problem with above code is sub procedure registered by onAction cannot be called because it looks like runMC has to be in Module. I cannot move these code to module because `Dim WithEvents engine As MCengine` requires to be declared in sheet object. so I am stuck in the middle. should I use other button callback method?

Does it mean I cannot use class with events in module? anyone can enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want this code to work for the entire workbook, this is why you use "Activesheet"?
If so, you need to paste the code in the Thisworkbook module.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal oSheet As Object)
    Dim btn As Button
    Dim rng As Range


    'Set engine = New MCengine
    With oSheet
        Set rng = .Range("E9")
        Set btn = .Buttons.Add(rng.Left, rng.Top, rng.Width, rng.Height)
        With btn
            .Caption = "Run MC simulation"
            .OnAction = "Thisworkbook.Test_btn"
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Sub Test_btn()

MsgBox "Ok"

End Sub
```

If not, you can paste it in a regular sheet module and sheet event:
private sub Worksheet_Activate, but take care that you define the correct sheet object in:

```
.OnAction = "Sheet1.Test_btn"
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working. I still get Cannot run marco. macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

Comment: Best check you can do is perform a right mouse click on the button created > assign macro, check the name of the macro (incl. sheet definition-> this is the name that you should put on the "OnAction" event) and figure out why it isn't connected. As my answer implicates, you can store the sub in the same sheet module without a problem. I tried it, and for me it works.

Comment: it is working now. thanks a lot, Kim. the reason is I rename sheet1 to constants and add new sheet. sheet name is sheet1 but key in worksheets is sheet4.